# How do I 'scale' a path?

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all, I'm a programmer with a less than stellar understanding of some areas of math. I am working on making a cheap approximation of a human silhouette, using only a few points representing limbs (left hand, left elbow, left shoulder, etc).

One method I was considering was drawing a path between each of those points, and then 'scaling' outwards. How would I calculate the vectors for these points along the path? From what I understand, that is what I am doing, creating vector points and scaling them outwards.

Currently I am able to accomplish what is at the left, drawing the path counter-clockwise using  (cos(2PI*x) , cos(2PI*y)). I just don't know what I need to do to have it draw the image on the left, some sort of vector multiplication?

[image]

Comment: The left wasn't $\cos(2 \pi x), \sin(2 \pi x)? $

Comment: You may get by without using math (unless using math is a goal in itself).
You are probably already using some graphics API - it may include ability to draw thick polylines. Just set the thickness equal to the radius of your circles, and the result will be the interior of the "silhouette". If you need only the outline, it's a bit more tricky, but can still be done without coding everything from scratch.

Comment: Ah typo, cos(2πx),sin(2πy). It is to some degree a goal in itself, I tend to take the route without math so I'm working on incorporating it more.

Comment: Are you asking for a method, given $x,y$ yields a line segment in the correct direction so that the black dashed border of the image on the right  occurs if we select those points?

Comment: Exactly. With how I know how to explain it, essentially scaling the path created between the two points, circularly.

Comment: To give a more complex example, do you need to obtain the red path given the green tree? [image](http://i.imgur.com/hJJsFeI.png)

Comment: Yes, exactly that path.

Comment: Is there a more general problem here than the image on teh right?

Comment: what is the tree? being referenced

Comment: In the image he attached, illustrating the stick-human shape. I used the image example because I imagined it would be the most general example of what I need, but if like you said, it is better on a case-by-case basis, how might that differ?

Comment: Okay so question 1: I am merely giving you a way to get the orientation of the line segments on that red path, but not the actual path itself, are you interested in the latter too?

Comment: This is much trickier

Comment: In the image I posted, just looking for the dotted line around the given (red) point. Or in Andris example, the red line around the green tree. Sorry if my explanations have been confusing!

Answer (score 1):

This is a cool problem. I believe it is fruitful not to try to find a single purpose formula but to do it by casework (otherwise it gets unnecessarily expensive, and if this is rendering on a front end that might be using up a user's resources unnecessarily)

Observe the right-picture (with circle radius r) can be approximated by calling it a half circle on top, two line segments interpolating both sides, and an upside-down half circle on the bottom.

The top half circle has center $(x_t, y_t)$ the bottom half circle has center $(x_b, y_b)$

From here we note we can get the correct vectors for the line segments by looking at

$$ \cos(2 \pi (x - x_t)) , \sin(2 \pi (y - y_t)) $$

For the top and

$$ \cos(2 \pi (x - x_b)), \sin(2 \pi (y - y_b)) $$

For the bottom.

Now the line segments that are adjacent are easily computed as just being $(0,1)$ since they are vertical lines. Observe that the vertical lines lines contain points p such that the $y$ component of p lies between $y_t, y_b$

So a sample routine you can build in python:

```
def direction(x,y,xt, yt,xb, yb): #outputs a pair
    if yt >= y: # we are not on the top circle
        if y >= yb: #we are above the bottom circle
            return (0,1)
        #we are on the bottom circle
        return (math.cos(2*math.PI*(x - xb)), math.sin(2*math.sin(2*math.PI*(y-yb))))

    #the first if statement failed so we must be on the top circle
   return (math.cos(2*math.PI*(x - xt)), math.sin(2*math.sin(2*math.PI*(y-yt))))
```

(untested, you might need to balance a parenthesis).

You might be interested in looking at "slope fields" they are very relevant here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field

---

General Purpose Solution:

---

Suppose you have an arbitrary path of points $(x_0,y_0), (x_1, y_1) ... $ If the path is sufficiently dense, what can do is just consider $\frac{1}{(x_{k+1}- x_k)^2 + (y_{k+1} - y_k)^2} \cdot (x_{k+1}-x_k, y_{k+1}-y_k)$ (the factor in front just makes it the right size (namely 1)).

If you sample a lot of points, even in the example ABOVE, this will do the trick. But if the sampling isn't dense then this won't be a very pretty image.

Answer (score 0):

The offset problem is a bit more complicated than may appear at first.
Here is a paper discussing a bit more general problem: [An offset algorithm for polyline curves](https://seant23.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/anoffsetalgorithm.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I don't necessarily think this will end up working for what I need, but I'm glad to know of this algorithm and to understand the problem more.